# Tomcat, wildcard subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, tomcat, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

Is this possible with Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Please use apache in front of tomcat for best results.
Use ajp connector and mod_proxy_ajp in your configs. Mod_jk is not that good as mod_proxy_ajp IMHO.
HTH